# How can I restore WCF session with same SessionId?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Hello) I have service with `InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession`

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
   public class SomeService : ISomeService
{

}
```

I store some service data in state service by SessionId key(I get SessionId from  **OperationContext.Current.SessionId**).

How can I restore WCF session with same SessionId after service reboot or fault?